# How to place 3.96 mm pitch components on 2.54 mm pitch PTH protoboard?

Tags: protoboard

I am trying to build a Clothes Dryer control board. Most components will have a 2.54 mm pitch - a few ICs, MOSFETs, and a Raspberry Pi Pico as the "brains". However, I wanted to retain the connectors from the Dryer parts which were all 3.96 mm pitch TE connectors.
On my new board design, I anticipate only the male 3.96 mm headers and since all the rest of the components are 2.54 mm pitch, I was thinking of using a protoboard of that pitch.

My challenge is how to fit these 3.96mm pitch components on it.

Comment: Drill holes to suit. Not too many other choices.

Comment: Thank you. I am fairly new to building electronic circuits, especially ones which will deal with higher voltages as found in appliances. So far, my experience has been all with microcontrollers and assorted components on a breadboard or some really small circuits, also on adafruit protoboards. So wasn't sure if there is a "trick" or best practice to doing these cross-pitch boards. Other than of course building a complete custom PCB.

Comment: protoboards with PTH are not really suitable for mains voltage circuits as the creepage distance is dictated by the PTH hole pitch and 2.54mm is too little.

Comment: Making custom PCB is easy and cheap. Your other option is to retain not only old connectors, but their PCB as well. Cut it to size, remove unused components, mount it mechanically onto you protoboard, make connections between the boards with suitable gauge wires.

Comment: You could also mount the mains-voltage components on a perf board (without plated-through holes) and run wires to your low voltage control board. Be careful mixing mains and low voltage wiring, generally it's best to have all wires rated for mains voltage even if they are reasonably well separated.

Comment: Thank you Kartman. Yes, I plan to isolate the high voltage to only a very small area of the circuit as opposed to the original design which ran many components on 110v.  @Maple, thanks! I didn't think of that! I guess the old board is fried anyway and I might as well dremel out the existing mounted headers and clean the conformal coating on it. Spehro, I think that is what I will end up with if I cut out small strips containing the headers from the existing damaged board and clean up the traces and any of the old circuits.